# NIC Teaming on 2012 R2 - Unidentified Network

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-teaming

I have a server running 2012 R2 that also has an HP 560-FLR SFP+ adapter. I've got 2 connections to that adapter split between 2 switches and I'm trying to setup a team to do some load-balancing. I'm using the teaming functionality that is native to Server 2012 R2. I was able to configure a team (Switch-Independent / Dynamic) and was able to assign an IP. For about a week, everything was working well. Sometime shortly thereafter, the connection went from Domain to Public and was receiving the "Unidentified Network" categorization. I've double-checked the NIC Team and everything looks correct. There is no longer any network connecitivty to this host and I'm perplexed as to why.

Initial research led me to:

http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2013/08/server-2012unidentified-network-with.html

But restarting the host/restarting NLA and then setting it to Delayed Start doesn't seem to correct the issue like it did for the page creator. I was under the impression because I'm using 'Switch-Independent' that I didn't need to worry overly much about my port configuration on the switches as it pertained to this.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `1.` Is the machine domain joined? `2.` I'm assuming that you assign ip addressing information to the team and not the individual team members, is that correct? If so, what DNS servers have you assigned to the team?

Comment: Yes, machine is domain joined. Yes, IP address has been configured on the Team, not the individual adapters. My DNS on the team is currently pointing to my primary and secondary domain controllers.

Comment: You mentioned two switches, both switches are on the same vlan right?

Comment: Thank you, Zoredache. You actually pointed me towards something I should've checked. I assumed the vlan config was right and when I popped in to take a look, I noticed that both port configurations were completely removed. I was able to add them back and now my team is functioning again. This was probably due to me and forgetting to save the running config. I'm not sure if I can accept a comment as an answer, but if you want to report your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it so you get the rep points. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but we found this.  Not sure if you are using LACP

https://vstepic.blogspot.com/2013/07/unidentified-network-on-teamed-interface.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.